# module descriptor file allowed import statements Why?

Tags: java, java-11, java-module, module-info

please anyone explain me module descriptor file allowed import Why? 
what is the used of `import` statement in module descriptor file.

```
import java.util.*;

module superman {
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One use would be if you were using the `provides` directive:

```
module superman {
    provides com.github.me.superhero.Superhero with com.github.me.superhero.Batman;
    provides com.github.me.superhero.Superhero with com.github.me.superhero.IronMan;
}
```

Using an import would look like:

```
import com.github.me.superhero.*;

module superman {
    provides Superhero with Batman;
    provides Superhero with IronMan;
}
```

Comment: [§7.3 Compilation Units](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3) of the JLS would seem to support this answer: "A _modular compilation unit_ consists of a `module` declaration (§7.7), optionally preceded by `import` declarations. The `import` declarations allow types from packages in this module and other modules, as well as `static` members of types, to be referred to using their simple names within the `module` declaration". Though interestingly I can't find anything in _§7.7 Module Declarations_ (including subsections) about import statements.

Comment: Also from [compilation unit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3) => `ModularCompilationUnit:
{ImportDeclaration} ModuleDeclaration`